# Adding a List to another List?

Tags: python

Trying to make a list of all words with a single label. When I split the different reviews into lists of words, I then attempt to add them to a variable called pos/neg_bag_of_words. This seems to work for one review, but when I iterate through the full corpus of reviews it seems to overwrite the previous list of words for one label and the other labels list gets a value of None. What am I doing wrong?

```
review1 = 'this dumbest films ever seen rips nearly ever'

review2 = 'whole mess there plot afterthought \
          acting goes there nothing good nothing honestly cant \
          understand this type nonsense gets produced actually'

review3 = 'released does somebody somewhere some stage think this \
          really load shite call crap like this that people'

review4 = 'downloading illegally trailer looks like completely \
          different film least have download haven wasted your \
          time money waste your time this painful'

labels = 'POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE'

reviews = [review1, review2, review3, review4]


for review, label in zip(reviews, labels):
    pos_bag_of_words = []
    neg_bag_of_words = []

    if label == 'NEGATIVE': 
#         neg_bag_of_words.extend(list(review.split()))
        neg_bag_of_words = list(review.split()) + neg_bag_of_words
    if label == 'POSITIVE':
#         pos_bag_of_words.extend(list(review.split()))
        pos_bag_of_words = list(review.split()) + pos_bag_of_words
```

**Returns**

```
#There are positive words in the entire corpus... but I get nothing
>>> pos_bag_of_words
    ['downloading',
 'illegally',
 'trailer',
 'looks',
 'like',
 'completely',
 'different',
 'film',
 'least',
 'have',
 'download',
 'haven',
 'wasted',
 'your',
 'time',
 'money',
 'waste',
 'your',
 'time',
 'this',
 'painful']

>>> neg_bag_of_words
[]
```

Comment: Your question title is correct that `list.extend` returns None.  But your code doesn't use `extend` anywhere.  And you didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, `list.extend()` returns `None`, and is documented as doing so. What is your question?

Comment: I need to extend or append a list to an other list..

Comment: What is your question?  You can extend a list using `extend()`, or append to it using `append()`.  Try reducing your question to a minimal example of code that can be run and demonstrates the issue you are experiencing.  Show the output it produces and the output you expect to have.

Comment: As an aside, `list(review.split())` is redundant, `review.split()` is sufficient since it returns a list.

Comment: So, seeing as your `neg_bag_of_words` list isn't coming up empty, the way you are adding to a list seems to be working at least in *some cases*. Clearly, there is either an error in your data or in the logic of how you are interpreting that data. It's hard to say without seeing an example input.

Comment: You don't need to keep `join`ing and `split`ting—you could leave `review` as a list after the first `split` since it seems to be used that way thereafter.  As for your problem, my best guess is that the `label` is never exactly equal to `'POSITIVE'`—perhaps a misspelling somewhere, or an error in the construction of the sequence `labels`?

Comment: 1. Labels isn't a list. 2. reviews doesn't exist.  Fix code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put initialization of your `neg_bag_of_words` and `pos_bag_of_words` outside your `for` loop. Otherwise every time your `for` loop executes, your lists get re-initialized to empty lists. This is why you are getting nothing for `neg_bag_of_words`. Do something like this:

```
pos_bag_of_words = []
neg_bag_of_words = []

for review, label in zip(reviews, labels):
    if label == 'NEGATIVE': 
        neg_bag_of_words = list(review.split()) + neg_bag_of_words
    if label == 'POSITIVE':
        pos_bag_of_words = list(review.split()) + pos_bag_of_words
```